# Presentation library

Tags: presentations, database

I have been giving regular presentations and classes over the years and all my slides have been in powerpoint, which has turned into a very difficult task to maintain.

I use latex for writing papers, manuscripts and books.

I am now looking for a solution in which I can store my presentations in chapters/sections into some sort of database, which is catalogued and when i then give a short seminar, I can compile pieces of all i have into a standard format.

I am aware I will have to rework all my slides for this purpose but before I start on this, looking around for the best solution.

Open to any suggestions and really appreciate the help

Comment: You should be familiar with beamer and/or texpower and pdfscreen.  No idea what sort of database you want.  I just use the "search files" feature of TexnicCenter to look for keywords.

Comment: As @JohnKormylo is saying, `beamer` may be a good package to check out. And LaTeX allows you to `\input` or `\include` some bits and pieces in a main file. I am actually doing precisely this: I have TeX files for the chapters/topics and include some of them for one presentation and some other for another presentation. All you need to do is to make sure that these files and the figures are in directories in which TeX finds them (`$TEXINPUTS`).

Comment: thanks for the recommendations. That is indeed a good idea. I can always build my own little contents database and a python interface to select from there visually and to then generate the overall file.